# iOS SWIFT Project Referencing an Objective-C Static Library

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am not an expert in iOS and trying to port my other platform app to iOS. When I reference an Objective-C static library in my SWIFT project I keep running into compiler issues. Can someone direct me to referencing right way?

Will it same as import mycustomlib ?

Vish

Comment: Did you search on SO before you ask this? At least those questions on the right side of the page?

Comment: This site, StackOverflow.